# Is it possible to get Dependabot statistics for a whole GitHub organisation?

Tags: security, github, dependabot

Is it possible to get Dependabot statistics for a whole GitHub organisation?

Comment: what kind of stats are you looking for?

Comment: I would like to be able to see how many vulnerabilities there are in each repo and this for an entire organisation.

Comment: For each repo, you should be able to see in some place like https://github.com/<repo>/<repo>/security/dependabot